# How to add strings to an existing object without replacing it in a loop?

Tags: php, array-push

I want to add $datasigned string value to the existing $data values, what should I do?

```
public function index(Request $request){
    $data = Apidata::select('file')->where('nim','=',$request->nim)->get();
    foreach($data as $berkas){
        $url = $berkas->file; 
        $berkas = (array)$berkas;
        // $filename = basename($url);
        // $file = storage_path().'/berkas/'.$filename;
        $pathfile = pathinfo($url);
        $datasigned = $pathfile['dirname'].'/'.$pathfile['filename'].'_signed.'.$pathfile['extension'];
        $berkas[]["file"] = $datasigned;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you are using laravel so maybe this will help you :

```
public function index(Request $request){
$data = Apidata::select('file')->where('nim','=',$request->nim)->get()->toArray();
foreach($data as $berkas){
    $url = $berkas["file"]; 
    // $filename = basename($url);
    // $file = storage_path().'/berkas/'.$filename;
    $pathfile = pathinfo($url);
    $datasigned = $pathfile['dirname'].'/'.$pathfile['filename'].'_signed.'.$pathfile['extension'];
    $berkas["file"]= $datasigned
}
return $data;
```

Or you can try :

```
public function index(Request $request){
$data = Apidata::select('file')->where('nim','=',$request->nim)->get();
foreach($data as $berkas){
    $url = $berkas->file; 
    $berkas = (array)$berkas
    // $filename = basename($url);
    // $file = storage_path().'/berkas/'.$filename;
    $pathfile = pathinfo($url);
    $datasigned = $pathfile['dirname'].'/'.$pathfile['filename'].'_signed.'.$pathfile['extension'];
    $berkas["file"] = $datasigned
}
return $data;
```

If you do not want to override "file" you can simply replace `$berkas["file"] = $datasigned` with `$berkas[]["file"] = $datasigned`

if you want to add it to data you have to create anew array is more simple do something like :

```
    public function index(Request $request){
    $data = Apidata::select('file')->where('nim','=',$request->nim)->get()->toArray();
    $newDaata = [];
    foreach($data as $berkas){
        $url = $berkas["file"]; 
        // $filename = basename($url);
        // $file = storage_path().'/berkas/'.$filename;
        $pathfile = pathinfo($url);
        $datasigned = $pathfile['dirname'].'/'.$pathfile['filename'].'_signed.'.$pathfile['extension'];
        $berkas["file"]= $datasigned
array_push($newData , $berkas);
    }
    return $newData;
```

Hope is yusefull

Comment: unfortunately still doesn't adding $datasigned to $data

Comment: I edited the answer i didn't understood first time hope the new code is better

Comment: with some modification of your new answer, now I can do it, thank you!

Comment: With pleasure mark it as solution please for other users who are having the same problem

Comment: btw I posted my answer, yes I'll mark it (EDIT: but I can only mark it in 2 days)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Troaca Mihai!

```
public function index(Request $request){
        $data = Apidata::select('file')->where('nim','=',$request->nim)->get()->toArray();
        $newData = [];
        foreach($data as $berkas){
            $url = $berkas["file"]; 
            // $filename = basename($url);
            // $file = storage_path().'/berkas/'.$filename;
            $pathfile = pathinfo($url);
            $datasigned = $pathfile['dirname'].'/'.$pathfile['filename'].'_signed.'.$pathfile['extension'];
            $berkas["file"]= $datasigned;
            array_push($newData , $berkas);
        }
        $combinedData = array_merge($data,$newData);
        return $combinedData;
    }
```